# Need to pull filename from path with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I need to get the following from this.

Source this.
"http://d12nw8z1-spapp/MemberDocuments/Applications/12-22-15%20New%20Ack%2090431.pdf
12-22-15 New Ack 90431.pdf"

I need this.
12-22-15 New Ack 90431.pdf

What is the expression?

Comment: You would not use a regular expression, but a URL decode function, and then you would tokenize the result using something path-aware. Regular expressions are too generic, there are better solutions for cases like these.

Comment: Would recommend python for this job. Just a quick one-liner to get the wanted result. And as @Cheatah said - no RegEx

Comment: I have a workflow engine that my software uses that has a pattern matching tool that uses Reg Express. It does not have a URL decoder and I have 5000 of these that I need to be reformated.

Comment: I just need an expression that says go right from left, find first period, move forward 3 character and capture until last "

Comment: Are you actually using macOS?

Comment: Yes it is one of many machines and OSs that I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
[\.][\w]*\s(.*)$
```

As the URI before your expected result is already encoded, we can assume that it's not going to contain any whitespace.

So in this regex, we're looking for a period `.` that's followed by some words `\w*` (for eg. pdf) which is further followed by a whitespace.

We're then capturing everything that follows. So the group 1 is our expected result.

Regex101 DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/CdO8fV/1

Comment: Perfect! Thank you that worked exactly as needed in my workflow engine